# Cronjob openshift not running a pod

Tags: kubernetes, cron, openshift, kubernetes-pod

Im trying to schedule a CronJob to launch a kubectl command. The cronjob does not start a pod.
This is my cronjob

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mariadump
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: mariadbdumpsa
          containers:
          - name: kubectl
            image: garland/kubectl:1.10.4
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl get pods;echo 'DDD'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I create the cronjob on openshift by:

```
oc create -f .\cron.yaml
```

Obtaining the following results

```
PS C:\Users\mymachine> oc create -f .\cron.yaml
cronjob.batch/mariadump created
PS C:\Users\mymachine> oc get cronjob -w
NAME        SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
mariadump   */1 * * * *   False     0        <none>          22s
mariadump   */1 * * * *   False     1        10s             40s
mariadump   */1 * * * *   False     0        20s             50s
PS C:\Users\mymachine> oc get pods -w
NAME                         READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
```

The cronjob does not start a pod, but if change to this cronjob(removing the serviceaccount)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mariadump
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: kubectl
            image: garland/kubectl:1.10.4
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl get pod;echo 'DDD'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

it works as expected without having permissions.

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> oc get cronjob -w
NAME        SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
mariadump   */1 * * * *   False     0        <none>          8s
mariadump   */1 * * * *   False     1        3s              61s
PS C:\Users\myuser> oc get pods -w
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mariadump-1616089500-mnfxs   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          8s

PS C:\Users\myuser> oc logs mariadump-1616089500-mnfxs
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "my-namespace"
```

For giving the cronjob the proper permissions I used this template to create the Role, the rolebinding and the ServiceAccount.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my_namespace
  name: mariadbdump
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  - replicasets
  verbs:
  - 'patch'
  - 'get'
​
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: mariadbdump
  namespace: my_namespace
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: mariadbdumpsa
  namespace: my_namespace
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: mariadbdump
  apiGroup: ""
  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mariadbdumpsa
  namespace: my_namespace
```

Anyone can help me to know why the cronjob with the ServiceAccount is not working?

Thanks

Comment: Did you created role, sa, rolebinding as you posted? There are some typose in your RBAC and cronjob. (SA name in cronjob and RBAC are different). Another issue can be that pod is executing container too fast and Kubernetes considering it failed. Please add `- sleep 30` in command and let me know if you still have issue with `CrashLoop`.

Comment: Sorry I copied here the wrong name of the SA but I run the correct one

Comment: I add the - sleep 30 and same is happening No pod is being created :(

Comment: Can you check/share the output of `kubectl describe cronjob -n my_namespace mariadump` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this yaml is actually working

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: mariadbdump
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - ''
    resources:
      - deployments
      - replicasets
      - pods
      - pods/exec
    verbs:
      - 'watch'
      - 'get'
      - 'create'
      - 'list'
      
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mariadbdump
  namespace: my-namespace
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: mariadbdumpsa
    namespace: my-namespace
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: mariadbdump
  apiGroup: ""
  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mariadbdumpsa
  namespace: my-namespace
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mariadump
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: mariadbdumpsa
          containers:
          - name: kubectl
            image: garland/kubectl:1.10.4
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods | grep Running | grep 'mariadb' | awk '{print $1}') -- /opt/rh/rh-mariadb102/root/usr/bin/mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u userdb --password=userdbpass databasename >/tmp/backup.sql;kubectl cp my-namespace/$(kubectl get pods | grep Running | grep 'mariadbdump' | awk '{print $1}'):/tmp/backup.sql my-namespace/$(kubectl get pods | grep Running | grep 'mariadb' | awk '{print $1}'):/tmp/backup.sql;echo 'Backup done'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```